# How to write the output of a python cgi script to user-specified file

Tags: python, cgi

I have a client/server arrangement which allows the user to submit a data file (picked via a filebrowser) and run the python cgi script.  This script writes the output to a file with a default hardcoded filename which the user then moves to wherever they want.

I would prefer to let the user specify the filename themselves using the usual filebrowser dialogue box but cannot get this to work.  I would greatly appreciate an example of how to make this work.
thanks

Comment: If I understood you right, you want user to specify file name in OPEN dialog? I think it's impossible. In OPEN dialog you can choose only what to open, not how to save it. You can write your own JS window when in one row - user selected file, in other - input box for renaming the file.

Comment: thanks - this is probably why my searching on the web failed to find anything.